# NB-Iot send UDP data to IPv6 with BC95-G via IPv6-only provider

Tags: nb-iot

**EDIT:** The question has changed after a reply from our network provider about the destination IP version.

I'm experience problems sending data to an IPv6 <strike>(or IPv4)</strike> address using BC95-G modem using IPv6 network provider.

Our NB-IoT provider states that:

- apn = "iot"
- PLMN = 20201
- Band = 20
- <strike>modem **has to be IPv6** and then it can send to both IPv4 or IPv6</strike>.
- modem **has to be IPv6** and then it can send to **IPv6 only**.

The provider also send us IPv6 SIM cards. The BC95 is supporting them and it seams it can open socket, but the send command fails.

Below you can find a demo listing. In that I try to open both Ipv4 and IPv6 sockets for demonstration purposes. After all they both fail:

```
AT+NRB

REBOOTING
Ά[0C][00]Ά[03]`
Boot: Unsigned
Security B.. Verified
Protocol A.. Verified
Apps A...... Verified

REBOOT_CAUSE_APPLICATION_AT
Neul 
OK
AT

OK
ATI

Quectel
BC95-G
Revision:BC95GJBR01A07

OK
AT+NCONFIG?

+NCONFIG:AUTOCONNECT,TRUE
+NCONFIG:CR_0354_0338_SCRAMBLING,TRUE
+NCONFIG:CR_0859_SI_AVOID,TRUE
+NCONFIG:COMBINE_ATTACH,FALSE
+NCONFIG:CELL_RESELECTION,TRUE
+NCONFIG:ENABLE_BIP,FALSE
+NCONFIG:MULTITONE,TRUE
+NCONFIG:NAS_SIM_POWER_SAVING_ENABLE,TRUE
+NCONFIG:BARRING_RELEASE_DELAY,64
+NCONFIG:RELEASE_VERSION,13
+NCONFIG:RPM,FALSE
+NCONFIG:SYNC_TIME_PERIOD,0
+NCONFIG:IPV6_GET_PREFIX_TIME,15
+NCONFIG:NB_CATEGORY,1
+NCONFIG:RAI,FALSE
+NCONFIG:HEAD_COMPRESS,FALSE
+NCONFIG:RLF_UPDATE,FALSE
+NCONFIG:CONNECTION_REESTABLISHMENT,FALSE
+NCONFIG:PCO_IE_TYPE,EPCO

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV6","iot" // or AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV4V6","iot"

OK
AT+COPS=1,2,"20201"

OK
AT+CEREG=1

OK
AT+CSCON=1

OK
AT+CFUN=1

OK
AT+CEREG?

+CEREG:1,1

OK
AT+CGATT?

+CGATT:1

OK
AT+CGPADDR

+CGPADDR:0,2A02:1388:400:B:2183:7DD4:B7F1:DE5A
+CGPADDR:1
OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ:13,99

OK
AT+NUESTATS

Signal power:-928
Total power:-862
TX power:210
TX time:549
RX time:27140
Cell ID:290888
ECL:0
SNR:114
EARFCN:6390
PCI:214
RSRQ:-108
OPERATOR MODE:2
CURRENT BAND:20

OK
AT+NSOCR=DGRAM,17,1024,1,"AF_INET6"

1

OK
AT+NSOCR=DGRAM,17,1025,1,"AF_INET"

2

OK
AT+NSOST=1,xx.xx.xx.xx,pp,2,4C47 // xx: IP address, pp: dest. port

ERROR
AT+NSOST=2,xx.xx.xx.xx,pp,2,4C47

ERROR
AT+NSOCL=1

OK
AT+NSOCL=2

OK
```

Note that:

- The listing is **exactly** the same if I use "IPV4V6" instead of "IPV6" in `AT+CGDCONT`
- The `AT+NSOST` command only supports IPv4 address arguments.

**EDIT:** How can I send to a IPv6 IP address using BC95-G?

With the same modem I can successfully send data using IPv4 SIMs(from vodafone). Does anyone succeed to send data using BC95-G and IPv6 SIM cards?

Thanks.

Comment: If your provider is only provisioning IPV6 addresses (or you are only asking for IPV6 vs IPV4V6) you won't be able to connect to a IPV4 address (without a [NAT64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT64) gateway).

Comment: I have asked that to our provider and I'm waiting for their response. But if this is true, how can I send to IPv6 address with BC95? The only command BC95 has for sending, is `AT+NSOST` and this command takes ONLY IPv4 address arguments.

Comment: Looking at the doc, I would say that you don't. You will have to find new hardware that supports IPv6

Comment: I'm also afraid about that. I've edited the question after a response from our network provider saying that the destination IP MUST be IPv6. It is weird though. A modem capable of obtaining IPv6, opening an IPv6 socket and yet not having a IPv6 send command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know(until now), there is only one solution to this problem. **Upgrade the firmware** of BC95-x.

After a discussion with quectel we came to conclusion that in order for `AT+NSOST` to work with ipv6 arguments, a new firmware must be running on the module. The version we tried is `R02A02`.

In order to upgrade the firmware someone will also need an upgrade tool. Quectel suggest QFlash. Unfortunately, things get a little tricky here.

- Don’t use a baud rate of 9600 (like if you want to send AT commands), but instead **use a baud rate of 115200**, where the boot loader is listening for your commands when booting up.
- When the QFlash application says “RESET” at the beginning of the update progress, you **need to** manually **reset** the BC95-G module. QFlash need to see the boot messages from module somehow. For example on "RESET" I applied the power to the module.

[Here](https://cloud.hoo2.net/index.php/s/xFt7nCeJnpR3SFZ) you can find both the firmware and the upgrade utility in a zip with md5:`89158f2384cb3fd086a972cdfb4efabb`.

After that, all seams to work.

```
AT+NRB

REBOOTING
Ά[0C]AΆ[04]A
Boot: Unsigned
Security B.. Verified
Protocol A.. Verified
Apps A...... Verified

REBOOT_CAUSE_APPLICATION_AT
Neul 
OK
AT

OK
ATI

Quectel
BC95-G
Revision:BC95GJBR02A02

OK
AT+NCONFIG?

+NCONFIG:AUTOCONNECT,TRUE
+NCONFIG:CR_0354_0338_SCRAMBLING,TRUE
+NCONFIG:CR_0859_SI_AVOID,TRUE
+NCONFIG:COMBINE_ATTACH,FALSE
+NCONFIG:CELL_RESELECTION,TRUE
+NCONFIG:ENABLE_BIP,FALSE
+NCONFIG:MULTITONE,TRUE
+NCONFIG:NAS_SIM_POWER_SAVING_ENABLE,TRUE
+NCONFIG:BARRING_RELEASE_DELAY,64
+NCONFIG:RELEASE_VERSION,13
+NCONFIG:RPM,FALSE
+NCONFIG:SYNC_TIME_PERIOD,0
+NCONFIG:IPV6_GET_PREFIX_TIME,15
+NCONFIG:NB_CATEGORY,2
+NCONFIG:RAI,FALSE
+NCONFIG:HEAD_COMPRESS,FALSE
+NCONFIG:RLF_UPDATE,TRUE
+NCONFIG:CONNECTION_REESTABLISHMENT,FALSE
+NCONFIG:TWO_HARQ,FALSE
+NCONFIG:PCO_IE_TYPE,EPCO
+NCONFIG:T3324_T3412_EXT_CHANGE_REPORT,FALSE
+NCONFIG:NON_IP_NO_SMS_ENABLE,FALSE
+NCONFIG:SUPPORT_SMS,TRUE
+NCONFIG:HPPLMN_SEARCH_ENABLE,TRUE

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IPV6","iot"

OK
AT+COPS=1,2,"20201"

OK
AT+CEREG=1

OK
AT+CSCON=1

OK
AT+CFUN=1

OK
AT+CEREG?

+CEREG:1,1

OK
AT+CGATT?

+CGATT:1

OK
AT+CGPADDR

+CGPADDR:0,2A02:1388:400:B:2183:7DD4:B7F1:DE5A
+CGPADDR:1
OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ:13,99

OK
AT+NUESTATS

Signal power:-928
Total power:-862
TX power:210
TX time:549
RX time:27140
Cell ID:290888
ECL:0
SNR:114
EARFCN:6390
PCI:214
RSRQ:-108
OPERATOR MODE:2
CURRENT BAND:20

OK
AT+NSOCR=DGRAM,17,1024,1,"AF_INET6"

1

OK
AT+NSOST=1,xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx,207,6,4C4700000000

1,6

OK

+CSCON:1
AT+NSOCL=1

OK

+CSCON:0
AT+CFUN=0

+CSCON:1

+CSCON:0

OK

+CEREG:0
```

Hopefully this will help others who have the same problem.